# ggplot2: remove geom_tile wired top and bottom block

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to plot a matrix using geom_tile. However, I noticed there are two strange blocks appear at the top and bottom of my plot. My initial guess was these are ticks element. I've tried to specify the theme parameters as far as I know but no luck.

Basically, I want to remove the two wired blocks that I marked in red arrow. The left plot is something that I desired except the white block. The right plot is I tuned the `plot.background` in `theme` to show you there are something I don't know occupies the area.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9xql.png)

I also attached the minimal code that could reproduce the left plot:

```
test2 <- matrix(runif(100*100),nrow = 100)
  
testdf <- test2 %>% reshape2::melt() 
testdf$Var2 <- factor(testdf$Var2,levels=(seq(max(testdf$Var2),1))) # you could ignore this line

testdf %>% ggplot() + geom_tile(aes(x=Var2,y=Var1,fill=log2(value+1))) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#ffffff","#f9c979","#ec8121","#b80217","#2f0006")) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
        plot.background = element_blank()) +   coord_equal()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These blocks are the result of ggplot2's default expansion of the scale. To get rid of these block set the expansion to zero via `scale_y_continuous`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

test2 <- matrix(runif(100*100),nrow = 100)

testdf <- reshape2::melt(test2) 
testdf$Var2 <- factor(testdf$Var2,levels=(seq(max(testdf$Var2),1))) # you could ignore this line

ggplot(testdf) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=Var2,y=Var1,fill=log2(value+1))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("#ffffff","#f9c979","#ec8121","#b80217","#2f0006")) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
        plot.background = element_blank()) + coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: Super fast and helpful! Thank you!